# $watch not detecting model change with checkbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I'm trying to do something relatively simple in angular and I can't figure out why it's not working. Ultimately I just want to perform one function when a checkbox is checked and then a different function when it's unchecked.

So I tried to use ng-model to evaluate foo to true or false if the checkbox is checked or unchecked and then I could do an if statement to pick a function. The {{foo}} in my view switches to true/false but the console.log always says undefined. Anyone know why?

HTML:

```
<div  ng-repeat="element in elements">
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="foo" /> {{foo}}
</div>
```

Script:

```
$scope.$watch('foo', function(){
    console.log($scope.foo);
});
```

EDIT: Oops! I had it in a repeat. Is there a way to achieve this effect inside a repeat?

Comment: it works for me. see the result in console. http://jsfiddle.net/x289d/

Comment: Note that you can use `ng-change`.

Comment: My mistake! I have it inside a ng-repeat. Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do inside a ng-repeat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What you did**

Your watcher is outside the `ngRepeat`. Your `ngModel` is inside the `ngRepeat`.

**What is wrong**

The inner `ngModel` creates a `foo` property on the inner scope. Your watcher reads the not existing `foo` property of the outer scope.

**Solution**

Have a `model` object for example, attached to your outer scope

```
$scope.model = { foo: false };
```

Have the inner `ngModel` set to `model.foo`.

**What is the difference ?**

Using this solution, the `ngModel` gets the right `model` object because of scope inheritance, what it does not try to do when assigning the `foo` property without traversing the prototype chain in what you wrote.